# How to add conditional expression for a table column in using html/handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to replace negative values with "NA" for the unitPrice column. I am using the dynamic templates from SendGrid. I am having some trouble. Ideally I would also like to say NA for subTotal if the unitPrice happens to be NA. Any hints would be appreciated!

```
<center>
<table id="item-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
      <th>Sub total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each items}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{#if (unitPrice >= 0)}} ${{unitPrice}} {{else}}NA{{/if}} </td>
      <td>{{subTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

I tried going through the handlebars docs. I am attempting to use their example but it's not working as intended. The NA would apply to all prices, not just those that are negative.

Comment: It looks like SendGrid has a helper for this: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#greaterthan